# Может ли автор размещать произведение под некоммерческой лицензией и использовать его в коммерческих целях?

Tags: лицензирование, авторские-права

Имеет ли право автор произведения, размещённого в открытом доступе под некоммерческой лицензией, использовать его в коммерческих целях?

Comment: Автор волен делать что хочет (например, конкурентно разместить свое творчество под ВСЕМИ существующими лицензиями), до тех пор пока не передал свои авторские права другому лицу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Лицензия", более полно - лицензионное соглашение - это условия, на которых автор разрешает использовать свое произведение. Лицензионные соглашения ограничивают пользователей, а не авторов.

---

Но тут есть тонкость. И она связана с принятием исправлений от сообщества, когда формат произведения допускает такую возможность. Если вы выкладываете свое произведение в открытый доступ - у кого-то может возникнуть желание доработать его. Если вы примите эти доработки - то перестанете быть единственным автором произведения и потеряете возможность использовать доработанное произведение под другими лицензиями.

Применительно к тому же github, любой принятый Pull Request лишает вас возможности сменить лицензию у проекта.

Крупные производители программного обеспечения решают эту проблему заключая со сторонними разработчиками соглашение о передаче (части) авторских прав автору исходного произведения.